# Mercurial - files modified in current branch

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-revsets

Can you help me to create a proper revset for mercurial `hg status` ?
I would like to list all the files that were changed in the current branch since it was created.
I tried

```
hg status --rev "branch(foo)"
```

where `foo` is the name of my branch, but this also lists files that were changed in the branch from which my branch was created (?). 
I don't get how to create a proper revset for this.

I created my branch and made several changes in multiple files. Now I want to reload these files in my application, but only them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward (see `hg help revsets` and `hg help revisions` for where this comes from).

We might start with the set of all commits in a branch, e.g., for branch `foo`:

```
-r 'branch(foo)'
```

Obviously this can produce a dozen, or even a million, revisions; but you want to see what happened between "branch creation"—which needs to examine the parent of the *first* such revision—and "current status of branch", which needs to examine the *last* such revision.

The first<sup>1</sup> revision of a large set is obtained by `first()` and the last by `last()`.  However, when various commands are given a revision specifier, they look it up as a single revision, and here a branch name suffices to name the last commit on the branch anyway.

To get the (first) parent of a revision, we use the `p1()` function (the suffix `^` is only allowed on a literal revision, not a function that returns a revision).  Hence the parent of the first revision on branch `foo` is:

```
-r 'p1(first(branch(foo)))'
```

To get a full diff of this against the last *commit* in the branch:

```
hg diff -r 'p1(first(branch(foo)))' -r 'foo'
```

But you don't want a full diff, you want the file names.  The command that produces this is `hg status`, and it has a slightly different syntax:

```
hg status --rev 'p1(first(branch(foo)))' --rev 'foo'
```

The status includes the letters at the front, as well as the names: `A` for newly added files, `M` for modified files, and so on.  Note the use of `--rev` rather than just `-r` (in fact, you can use `--rev` with `hg diff` as well).

Note that there's a much shorter syntax, `::foo`, that gets all the ancestors of the given branch up to and including the last revision in the named branch.  However, this gets *too many* ancestors.  You can, however, use `p1(first(branch(foo)))::foo` as the (entire) argument to `--rev`, and this also works. so:

```
hg status --rev 'p1(first(branch(foo)))::foo`
```

is a slightly shorter way to express this.

Last, note that comparing the first commit in the branch to the last (as would happen with `hg status --rev 'first(branch(foo))' --rev foo`, for instance) can miss changes made in that first commit on the branch.  That's why we use `p1` here.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `first` function selects the first in the set, which may not be the same as the numerically-first revision.  For instance, suppose the set is made from `x | y` and a revision in `y` is numerically lower than a revision in `x`, or you use `reverse(branch(foo))` to put the commits in high-to-low order.  In this case, `min` instead of `first` would be the function to use.